# AngularJS $http to retrieve external javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a 3rd party form solution that I can embed in my site by importing a javascript file. The instructions for embedding the script is actually along the lines of
"Copy and paste this:"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://<form.company.com>/<form_name>.js"></script>
```

Taking a look in the actual javascript file, it's basically just a set of

```
document.write("            <input id=\"SubmitButton2070990\""+"\n");
document.write("            class=\"fsSubmitButton\""+"\n");
document.write("            style=\"display: block;\""+"\n");
document.write("            type=\"submit\""+"\n");
document.write("            value=\"Submit Form\" />"+"\n");
```

Now, I've tried a couple of things...
I've got a directive with a template URL that hits a simple partial that has that script within.
It looks like this:

**directive:**

```
angular.directive('feedbackForm',function() {
return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: '/static/form.html'
        };
)
```

**form.html**

```
<div>
<h2>testing form</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://<form.company.com>/<form_name>.js"></script></div>
</div>
```

All that happens is that the html is rendered, but the contents of the script aren't...

I've tried a `$http` request that gets the contents of the script from that 3rd party's link as above, and tries to execute it.
Something like

```
$http.get('https://<form.company.com>/<form_name>.js')
    .then(function(response){
        var formScript = new Function(response.data);
        formScript();
    })
```

But, the network tab in my browser shows that while the request is sent with a 200 response code, the response has no contents, is 0 bytes, etc etc.

Basically, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Is it actually possible for me to do this? Is there some cross domain scripting type thing that I'm running up against?

Comment: Aside from the obvious XSS issues, why do you want to do this?

Comment: To embed a 3rd party form solution within my Angular based SPA.

Comment: can you not include it in a normal script tag?

Comment: That's what I did in my first attempt. I've just edited my post to include what I tried the first time, where I've got a directive that just has a templateUrl that gets that html page that has that tag in it, but I don't see the script being requested in the network tab, so it's definitely not working the way I'd normally expect it to.

Comment: is your url *actually* `<form.company.com>`? sorry, I know it's a silly question

Comment: nah, it's a fake url, but it IS a 3rd party company separate from mine.

Comment: I think the point is you're having a script tag inside a template loaded by angular. This isn't possible. I just read that script tags are stripped for security reasons (see this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/9d-rhMiXDmg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how scripts should be treated in templates.

```
app.directive('directive', function () {
    return {
        template: '<script src="404.js"><\/script>' +
          '<script>console.log("inline script");<\/script>',
        link: function (element, attrs) {
            var scripts = element.find('script');
            angular.forEach(scripts, function (script) {
                script = angular.element(script);
                var type = script.attr('type');
                var src = script.attr('src');

                if (type && !type.match(/^(?:text|application)\/javascript$/i))
                    return;

                var scriptFixed = angular.element('<script>');
                if (src) {
                    scriptFixed.attr('src', src);
                } else {
                    scriptFixed.text(script.text());
                }
                script.replaceWith(scriptFixed);                    
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You will obviously have XSS issues when requesting the scripts with $http.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! Then I ran into problems with the browser not allowing async-downloaded scripts to write to the document... At which point I gave up and went looking for a way to embed this in an iframe. :) Regardless, thank you! I've learnt something new :)