# Pass script in angular scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to pass a javascript code through angular scope but on view page it renders as text. I also tried ng-Sanitize but it also didn't work.

```
&lt;div id=&quot;xv-embed-13042533&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt; (function() { var tn = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;); tn.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;; tn.async = true; tn.src = &#39;http://flashservice.example.com/embedcode/13042533/510/400/embed.js&#39;; var s = document.getElementById(&#39;xv-embed-13042533&#39;); s.parentNode.insertBefore(tn, s); })(); &lt;/script&gt;
```

But on View page it renders as text in below format

```
<div id="xv-embed-13042533"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var tn = document.createElement('script'); tn.type = 'text/javascript'; tn.async = true; tn.src = 'http://flashservice.example.com/embedcode/13042533/510/400/embed.js'; var s = document.getElementById('xv-embed-13042533'); s.parentNode.insertBefore(tn, s); })(); </script>
```

I'm using below syntax

```html
<div id="Div2" ng-bind-html="htmltext2"></div> <br/>
```

Comment: Read the tag descriptions!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$sce.trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)

```
$scope.unsafeHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<script>...<\/script>');
```

in conjunction with `ng-bind-html`

```
<div ng-bind-html="unsafeHtml"></div>
```

However, the above will not work, because jqLite doesn't handle `<script>` correctly. You have to resort to [such workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455217/angularjs-http-to-retrieve-external-javascript-file/31461083#31461083) or load jQuery before Angular, so jQuery would be used as `angular.element` instead of jqLite.

Here's [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iVre7ZZuBPZvY6XJcOvh?p=preview).

Comment: I have already created "sanitize" filter but that's not working

Comment: You didn't provide fully testable example. Here's a working one, it does exactly the same as the answer says http://plnkr.co/edit/iVre7ZZuBPZvY6XJcOvh?p=preview