# AngularJS doesn't compiles expressions inside the script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to compile HTML template with `<script>..</script>` inside the file, but AngularJS compiler doesn't compile all expressions within `<script>` tag.

My controller:

```
.controller('showChannelController', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $compile, $templateRequest) {
        $http.get("http://localhost/show?id=" + $stateParams.id)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.info = response.data.data;
                $templateRequest('application/script.html').then(function(template) {
                    $('body').append($compile(template)($scope));
                });
            });
    });
```

And my `application/script.html` template looks like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
        // Load Player
        var player = new Clappr.Player({
            source: "{{source_url}}",
            parentId: "#player",
            autoPlay: true,
            width: 962,
            height: 540,
        });
});
</script>
```

Is it possible resolve this issue without include backend?

Comment: If the script is inside ng-view, you should call Jquery before AngularJS in your index.html file. Btw this must be a duplicate

Comment: The script is located in `application/script.html`. Can you give me an example?

Comment: You will be able to execute <script> tags in templates with jQuery trick (they aren't executed at all without it), but you won't be able to use expressions there (it would be a huge security breach, because this is pure `eval`). Just don't do that. Create a player directive instead.

Comment: In your index.html, you have some <script> tag calling AngularJS Library ? You must have it in order to have angularJS.
You should have one for Jquery too, then care about calling the Jquery tag before the Angular one

Comment: But yes of course as estus precised, it is not the Angular way to do it. :) See here some examples  https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp

Comment: @estus can you give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use `<script>` tags in templates with [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461083/3731501) or by having jQuery loaded (it replaces Angular jqLite implementation and treats script nodes differently).

But it is not possible to use Angular expressions in scripts. It would be a huge security breach, because this would require to execute arbitrary code with `eval`.

It can be a directive that contains the code above.

```
app.directive('player', () => ({
  scope: { url: '@' },
  link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
    scope.id = Math.round(Math.random()*10e4);
    attrs.$set('id', 'player-' + scope.id);

    scope.instance = new Clappr.Player({
      source: scope.url,
      parentId: '#' + scope.id,
      ...
    });
  }
}));
```

It depends on how `Clappr.Player` allows to provide parent element. If it accepts DOM element as a parent, `$element[0]` could be provided instead of `parentId

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the brackets. Use the variable. 
It should work straight forward.
Pass the value of variable using say $rootScope. Here $rootScope is used since it is common across all application.

Here is the example.

```
angular.module('tss.application').controller('VideoController',function($log, $rootScope, $scope, $window ) {

    var player = new Clappr.Player({
                                    source:  $rootScope.vp, 
                                    parentId: "#player", 
                                    autoPlay: true
                                    });

});
```

I use this controller inside video_modal.html --- This is a popover modal in which player opens. The source of the video is dynamic as per the user click/choice.

```
<div ng-controller="VideoController">
  <div id="player"></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement backend version, just generates script with all needed parameters on the server side and transfer complete script to AngularJS. Then apply received data in the AngularJS controller.

```
$('body').append($compile(response.data.script)($scope));
```